# Error saving RDD into HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, cloudera

I'm trying to save a RDD into HDFS using Scala and I get this error:

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, quickstart.cloudera, executor 3): java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1020)
        at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:452)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toFloat(StringLike.scala:231)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toFloat(StringOps.scala:31)
        at $line24.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
        at $line24.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$7.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1196)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1195)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1195)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1279)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1203)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1183)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

First, I read a file located into HDFS and it reads correctly. After, I try to make some transformations like changing field delimiters (pipes) and then write it back into HDFS. Here is my code if someone can help me.

```
val productsRDD= sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/products/products")
val products2RDD=productsRDD.map(a=>a.split(","))
case class clas1(product_id: Int,product_category_id: Int,product_name: String,product_description: String,product_price: Float,product_image: String)
val products = products2RDD.map(b => clas1(Integer.parseInt(0),Integer.parseInt(1),(2).toString,(3).toString,(4).toFloat,(5).toString))
val r = products.toDF()
r.registerTempTable("productsDF")
val prodDF = sqlContext.sql("select * from productsDF where product_price > 100")

/* everything goes fine until this line*/

prodDF.map(c => c(0)+"|"+c(1)+"|"+c(2)+"|"+c(3)+"|"+c(4)+"|"+c(5)).saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/problem1/pipes1")
```

The fields of the Data Frame:

```
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| product_id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_category_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_name        | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_description | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_price       | float        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_image       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

I'm new with Scala and I appreciate your help...
thank you!

Comment: Which part of `NumberFormatException: empty String` did you miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking from your error - java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

it looks like that your error exists while you are trying to parse integer from String for which string is empty, so you will this particular erorr.

What you can do is you can use coalesce before doing transformation and after splitting. Create a dataframe and there is a coalesce feature in spark-sql that will replace your null values with "NULL"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of CDH, Spark2 has a **builtin** CSV reader.

```
case class Product(product_id: Int,product_category_id: Int,product_name: String,product_description: String,product_price: Float,product_image: String)

val productsDs = spark.csv("/user/cloudera/products/products").as[Product]
val expensiveProducts = productDs.where($"product_price" > 100.0)
```

If not using Spark2, you should definitely upgrade some local clients to point to your same YARN cluster, or use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) to not have to deal with a poor CSV parser of `map(... split(","))`

Note: I don't know if the case class will work anyway if your columns are empty as the error says

And if all you're trying to do is change a delimiter, you can write it out too using CSV formatter

```
expensiveProducts.write
    .option("sep", "|")
    .csv("/user/cloudera/problem1/pipes1")
```

Comment: Thank you Cricket_007 :). My Spark version is 1.6, I will upgrade it to Spark2. But if the problem is that I have empty fields, how can I save them (Or fill with "NULL") in my case ?

Comment: If you see the libraries in linked to, it mentions permissive mode and a null string option, which I believe will work, but that should also be possible to address that with at least Spark 2.0.1 https://medium.com/@mrpowers/sparks-treatment-of-empty-strings-and-null-values-in-csv-files-80748893451f